# rga package how to get all Google Analytics profiles

Tags: r, google-analytics, rstudio

I'm using RStudio and the rga package to extract some Google Analytics data.  One issue I'm running into is during the `ga$getProfiles()` call.  I'm getting the first 1000 profiles -- I have more than 1000 profiles but I'm not sure how to specify that I'd like ALL the profile ID's to be pulled down.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly it is important to be aware that there are two different rga/RGA packages.

rga - is available from github (i started with this)
RGA - is a package available in CRAN (I now use this due to clearer authentication, function calls and documentation)

```
install.packages("RGA")
```

With RGA you will need to create a google developer account though but you can find out how to do this in the reference manual http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RGA/RGA.pdf

if you install the new RGA package then you can just add the `max.results` parameter with a suitable threshold.

```
list_profiles(max.results=NULL)
```

if you want to stick with rga, it will be a similar case and I am pretty confident you would do it as

```
ga$get_profiles(max=10000)
```

Comment: You're right -- I'm using the "rga" package, not "RGA".  However the syntax for "rga" to return profiles is ga$getProfiles().  When I add the max.results parameter: ga$getProfiles(max.results=10000) R returns an error: Error in ga$getProfiles(max.results = 10000) : unused argument (max.results = 10000)

Comment: Instead try `ga$get_profiles(max=10000)` the documentation on rga is very limited. Which is one of the reasons I switched to RGA. The only way I found the above code is by looking through the R scripts in the github package https://github.com/skardhamar/rga/blob/master/R/mgmt.R

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RGA/functions/get_profiles there is a parameter called `max.results`, which should be what you need. And if the max is 1000, then use `start.index` parameter to start at e.g., 1001, and then get the next 1000 results, e.,g,

Comment: ga$getProfiles(max.results = 1200) returns: Error in ga$getProfiles(max.results = 1200) : 
  unused argument (max.results = 1200)

Comment: @davids12 woops, right, that would work with the `RGA` package, not the `rga` package

Comment: I switched to RGA, any idea why I would recieve this error message for the following code? ga_token <- authorize(client.id = "xxxxx", client.secret = "xxxxx")

test <- get_profiles(start.index = NULL, max.results = 10000, token = ga_token,verbose = getOption("rga.verbose", FALSE)) Error: String does not contain valid JSON: "Not Found..."